# React Native Issue Android App not installing issue

Tags: react-native

when i run npm start for my react native proj and mobile connected through wire and select run app on android option , a cursor is just blinking with written before, info js already running and opening app on mobile but nothing is happening just cursor blinking,I tried waiting for about 10 mins, i was expecting that an android app will open and install on my mobile by itself but nothing happens.

Comment: When you install android application first time, it's taking time. It also depends on the system config and internet bandwidth